# Blazor webassembly: detect from which site the user came from

Tags: http, request, blazor, webassembly, referer

I am developing a Blazor Webassembly application. Based on the page the user came from, I should show different content. For example, the app should show Content A when the user came from Facebook and Content B otherwise. How can this feature achieved?

I red that one could do this by checking the referrer property of the request header, but I don't know how to access the http request on a razor page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use javascript for this.

1) Create a javascript file on your blazor project (the front-end) with the following content:

```
function getReferrer() {
    return document.referrer;
}
```

2) Add the previous file to your index.html file:

```
<script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
```

3) Consume the function using the IJSRuntime service:

```
var referrer = await js.InvokeAsync<string>("getReferrer");
```

This should get you the referrer.

Comment: Thank you Felipe. I did what you suggested, and now the getReferrer JS function always return undefined even when I go to the page from a link placed on my different web page. Please suggest a method how could I test the above.

Comment: I uploaded a small sample project to github, can you test using that project? https://github.com/gavilanch/BlazorReferrerSample

Comment: I think we're almost there :)
Your solution works, mine doesn't. I think this is because your application's url is https and mine is http. Do yo know how can I make mine app https?

Comment: Right click your "Server" project, go to properties, then go to Debug, make sure enable SSL is checked. That should give you https.